# BeautifulSoup: No tables found

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read a table from [this address](https://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=vKY6UkQt1U7B2iMfDOOH1g%3D%3D&rt=5&let=6&ct=0&ft=-1&sheetId=1) by selenium;
I tried different ways, this is the result of using **BeautifulSoup**

.py code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
import shutil


def getfipiraninfo():
    address = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    address = os.path.dirname(address)
    address = os.path.join(address, 'geckodriver.exe')
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['marionette.contentListener'] = True
    profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist'] = False
    profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level'] = 0
    profile.set_preference('webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer', False)
    profile.set_preference("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", True)
    profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
    capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 0)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:/Users/Achilles/PycharmProjects/Pandas")
    options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.viewableInternally.enabledTypes", "")
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                           "text/plain,application/pdf,"
                           "text/csv,application/zip,application/octet-stream,"
                           "application/ms-excel; charset=utf-8,"
                           "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=address, options=options, firefox_profile=profile, capabilities=capabilities)
    try:
        symbol = "های وب"
        driver.get("https://codal.ir/ReportList.aspx?search&Symbol=" + symbol +
                   "&LetterCode=%D9%86-10&LetterType=-1&Isic=731003&AuditorRef=-1&PageNumber=1&Audited&NotAudited&IsNotAudited=false&Childs=false&Mains&Publisher=false&CompanyState=0&Category=1&CompanyType=1&Consolidatable&NotConsolidatable")
    except HTTPError as herr:
        print(f'The Page Is Not Found On The Server: {herr}')
    except URLError as uerr:
        print(f'The Server Could Not Found: {uerr}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
    except ConnectionError as cerr:
        print(f'Connection error occurred: {cerr}')
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span/a").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
        driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
        sorat = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ddlTable"]')
        for option in sorat.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
            print('ok1')
            if option.text == 'صورت سود و زیان':
                print('ok2')
                option.click()
                print('ok3')
            break
        address1 = driver.current_url
        page = requests.get(address1, verify=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        tbl = soup.find_all("table")
        print('ok4')
        print(tbl)
        data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
        print(data_frame)


test = getfipiraninfo()
```

result:

```
C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Achilles/PycharmProjects/Pandas/codal.py
C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\codal.py:69: DeprecationWarning: use driver.switch_to.window instead
  driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
ok1
ok2
ok3
C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'codal.ir'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
ok4
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\codal.py", line 103, in <module>
    test = getfipiraninfo()
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\codal.py", line 84, in getfipiraninfo
    data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1085, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 913, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 893, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Achilles\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 543, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The error is from line 84. Failed to find any tables. Using pandas.read_html is exactly the same.I do not notice the problem, the table was separated from several other sites in the same way, but it does not work for this address.Does anyone have a solution to convert this table to a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the table, see this example:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=vKY6UkQt1U7B2iMfDOOH1g%3D%3D&rt=5&let=6&ct=0&ft=-1&sheetId=1"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

df = pd.read_html(
    str(soup.find("table", class_="rayanDynamicStatement"))
)
print(df)
```